# Storing date and time into MySQL using Slick/Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, date, slick

I have what appears to be a simple problem, and wish there was a simple solution. But I have not found it yet.

My attributes in MySQL are of types DATE and TIMESTAMP. 
These are my slick classes:

```
case class Event (
  id: Long, name: String, category: String, date: Date, venue: String, startTime: Date, endTime: Date, description: String, admission: String, addInfo: Option[String])

class Events(tag: Tag) extends Table[Event](tag, "EVENT") {

  implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Date, Long](d => d.getTime, d => new Date(d))

  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def category = column[String]("CATEGORY")
  def date = column[Date]("DATE")
  def venue = column[String]("VENUE")
  def startTime = column[Timestamp]("START_TIME")
  def endTime = column[Timestamp]("END_TIME")
  def description = column[String]("DESCRIPTION")
  def admission = column[String]("ADMISSION")
  def addInfo = column[String]("ADD_INFO")

  def * = (id, name, category, date, venue, startTime, endTime, description, admission, addInfo.?) <> (Event.tupled, Event.unapply _)
}
```

For some reason, I can't get this to work. The main issue seems to be how to store java.util.Date into both DATE and TIMESTAMP types in MySQL.

Can someone advise how best to do this?? I'm fairly new to the Scala/Slick world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to store  java.util.Date into both DATE and TIMESTAMP types in MySQL so you need to define to conversion :

1) java.util.Date => java.sql.Date

2) java.util.Date => java.sql.Timestamp

```
class Events(tag: Tag) extends Table[Event](tag, "EVENT") {
   def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
   def name = column[String]("NAME")
   def category = column[String]("CATEGORY")
   def date = column[Date]("DATE")(DateMapper.utilDate2SqlDate)
   def venue = column[String]("VENUE")
   def startTime = column[Date]("START_TIME") (DateMapper.utilDate2SqlTimestampMapper)
   def endTime = column[Date]("END_TIME")(DateMapper.utilDate2SqlTimestampMapper)
   def description = column[String]("DESCRIPTION")
   def admission = column[String]("ADMISSION")
   def addInfo = column[Option[String]]("ADD_INFO")

   def * = (id, name, category, date, venue, startTime, endTime, description, admission, addInfo) <> (Event.tupled, Event.unapply)
}



object DateMapper {

    val utilDate2SqlTimestampMapper = MappedColumnType.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp](
{ utilDate => new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime()) },
{ sqlTimestamp => new java.util.Date(sqlTimestamp.getTime()) })

   val utilDate2SqlDate = MappedColumnType.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Date](
{ utilDate => new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()) },
{ sqlDate => new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime()) })

}
```

Comment: Thank you Sky, worked in first attempt! Can this conversion be implicit?

Comment: @Raaj no , Because  there are two conversion which  have same input type parameter(java.util.Date) so compile does not understand which one use java.util.Date => java.sql.Date or java.util.Date => java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: @Raaj I would like to suggest in database always save timestamp instead of Date. If you are saving date , It mean you just lost hour and minute, second.

Comment: Agreed. I had it as Timestamp in the beginning however I really need only the event date since times are captured in startTime and endTime.

Comment: Is this solution applicable to Slick 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [slick-joda-wrapper](https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper)? You may also want to checkout more Scala friendly wrapper around Joda too: https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time

Comment: I started looking into Joda time, but thought there could be a straightforward way. I will definitely look into nscala-time. Thank you!